# How can I remove a sign and fill signature from a form using a button?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

[image]So, I am working on a PDF form for workplace use, the idea is for the employee to fill his information and send it to me by e-mail. I've coded a simple "clear form" button in adobe javascript, so the technitian filling the form wouldn't need to close it and open it every time he gets to a new employee. The problem is: the technitian is using a tablet, and both of them need to sign the form, using the tablet's pen, I used the "Fill and Sign" feature, because it's the only way I see of doing it, the problem is: my "clear form" button does not work for it, it can't remove the signature, I've tried a lot of code but nothing seems to work, this is my current "clear button" code:

```
//Clears all the fields on the form
this.resetForm();
this.getField("start").readonly = false;
this.getField("end").readonly = false;
this.getField("Date1").readonly = false;
this.getField("Date2").readonly = false;
this.getField("Send").enabled = enabled.true;
this.getField("Send").display = display.visible;
```

How can I make it work? Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any html/view you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear signature field by defining of signature field name within the function `resetForm`:

```
this.resetForm(["SignatureFieldName"]);
```